# Type parameter t has incompatible upper bounds view and listview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, listview, compiler-errors

I have the error when I initialize the list view `findViewById(R.id.listview)`

> error: incompatible types: no unique maximal instance exists for type
>   variable T with upper bounds ListView,View where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

```
public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    }
}
```

Comment: Rename your activity name to ListView to ListViewActivity.
because  when you are declaring this ListView listview;
listview become Activity type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your activity name to `ListView` to `ListViewActivity`.

Because when you are declaring `ListView listview;` listview becomes Activity type.